# Member classes versus #includes

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I've recently discovered that it is bad form to have `#include`s in your header files because anyone who uses your code gets all those extra includes they won't necessarily want.

However, for classes that have member variables defined as a type of another class, what's the alternative?

For example, I was doing things the following way for the longest time:

```
/* Header file for class myGrades */
#include <vector>           //bad
#include "classResult.h"    //bad

class myGrades
{
    vector<classResult> grades;
    int average;
    int bestScore;
}
```

(Please excuse the fact that this is a highly artificial example)

So, if I want to get rid of the `#include` lines, is there any way I can keep the `vector` or do I have to approach programming my code in an entirely different way?

Comment: How did you make this "recent discovery"?

Comment: Hmm, apparently I've been using "bad form" for ~30 years. I better shape up. :)

Comment: A related comment: what you absolutely mustn't do is to say things like 'using namespace std' in your .h files. Your code wouldn't compile in its current form anyway -- you should type std::vector instead of plain 'vector'.

Comment: you must have misheard.  It is bad practice to include a namespace inside header files.

Answer (score 3):

If your class directly includes a data member of a given type (and not, by the way, a pointer to that type or a reference to that type), then you must have the class declaration available so that the compiler knows how many bytes an instance of your object takes up.  This usually means that you have to `#include` the header files.

However, there are techniques known as compiler firewalls that can let you structure classes in a way that gives the class access to objects of the appropriate type without directly including them.  One of these is the [pImpl idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm), in which your class implementation looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    /* ... */

private:
    struct Impl;
    Impl* pImpl;
};
```

Here, you forward-declare a struct `Impl` containing your class's implementation, then store a pointer to the `Impl` struct in the class.  Since having a pointer in your class doesn't require the size of the object being pointed at to be known, this is perfectly fine.  Then, in the .cpp file, you can define the `Impl` struct:

```
struct MyClass::Impl {
    /* ... */
};
```

and you can implement all of the class's member functions by just following the `pImpl` pointer to the actual fields.  This has the drawback that all field accesses require a pointer indirection, but the ability to change the class implementation so quickly does make this useful.

Another option along the same lines is to make the class an abstract base class, then to provide a static factor function that returns an object subclassing your base class that actually contains the implementation.  For example:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    virtual ~MyClass(); /* Need virtual dtors in polymorphic classes! */

    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    /* ... etc. ... */

    static MyClass* New(/* ... args ... */);
};
```

Then, in the .cpp file you can define a concrete subclass of `MyClass` that actually does all the work:

```
class ActualClass: public MyClass {
public:
     void doSomething();
     /* ... etc. ... */

private:
     /* ... data members ... */
}
```

and finally, implement `New` to create a new instance of the implementation class:

```
MyClass* MyClass::New(/* ... args ... */) {
    return new ActualClass(/* ... args ... */);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would "pimpl" require `new` on all objects? Or is there a way to reference without allocating so much stuff on the heap? Either way, +1

Comment: @Marlon- pImpl requires an allocation every time an object of the given type is created, since the `Impl` has to live somewhere in memory.  You can do some clever stuff with custom allocators to prevent this, but you have to be very careful not to break alignment guarantees while doing so.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with including other headers in your header.

You need to be sure that your header includes all of the headers that it depends upon and you should avoid including extraneous, unneeded headers.

Answer (score 2):

> it is bad form to have #includes in
>   your header files

I don't think you can say that with that amount of certainty. If you have a function in a header file that takes a std::vector, you really can't avoid including that header file.

You're right that you shouldn't have UNNECESSARY includes in your header files. If you need something for your implementation that doesn't need to be exposed in your header file, keep it in your implementation.

But I wouldn't go out of my way to not include stuff in your headers.

Answer (score 1):

*I've recently discovered that it is bad form to have #includes in your header files because anyone who uses your code gets all those extra includes they won't necessarily want.*

...and as you're now finding out, that's not exactly as great as it sounds.  It's always great to reduce your dependencies, and if you can use a name without having to know what it looks like, then forward declarations are better...but whoever told you it's bad form to have includes in your header is just plain FOS.

What those who use your code WANT is utterly beside the point.  If they're going to use your class then they NEED all the definitions to the objects your class directly depends on (not just name dependencies).  If you are using a member variable of type WTF then *someone* simply HAS to include the header for WTF in order to use your class, and it has to be included before your class definition.  It is MUCH, MUCH, MUCH better to include such headers yourself so that clients of your class don't have to figure out where the fsck WTF is defined and include it before including your class's header.

In other words, do exactly the OPPOSITE of what you've been told.  It is GOOD form to include all the headers that are necessary to declare your class.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
I don't agree that inlcluding headers is bad. If it's needed, it's needed.
If you forward declare a class you do not need to include the header file, however this can be used  if your member variables are pointers or references.

I do use forward declaration whenever possible.
However I would not change a class member just to avoid including the header file as I do not see anything wrong with that.

Comment: Simply have to -1 this.  Posting code as an answer and then saying "don't do it like that" isn't exactly beneficial.  Show how to do it RIGHT or not at all.

Comment: @Noah, indeed my answer is not that useful as it stands now. I will edit it to make the intent clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems not everyone agrees with reducing header file dependencies, but i definitely do.  As the size of projects increases, unnecessary includes greatly increases the build time of individual compilation units, and means more code needs to be rebuilt when you make a change.

It is often a good idea to have one header file which includes only the bare minimum amount for the compiler to know the size of the object, and another which contains any inline function definitions.  sizeof(vector) is typically 2*sizeof(classResult*), it does not depend on what is in classResult, so in the initial example, you only need to forward declare classResult.

C++ has an annoying quirk where a struct must be forward declared as a struct, and a class must be forward declared as a class, despite the two really being the same thing other than whether members default to public or private.  Never the less, in general, use forward declarations as much as possible, as they can massively reduce header file dependencies.

The pimpl idiom mentioned above can also be useful, but needs some care as to when and where it is used, as it can hurt runtime performance by requiring an extra indirection.  If the object is only ever created on the heap, then you can make the ctor private, and instead have a public static factory method.  The implementations of the function can cast then this to the real type, eg.

```
// In header file
class Foo
{
public:

    static Foo * Create();

    void DoSomething();

private:
    Foo();
    Foo( const Foo & );
    Foo & operator=( const Foo & );
};


// In c++ file
struct FooImplementation
{
    int bar;
};

Foo * Foo::Create()
{
    return (Foo*) new FooImplementation;
}

#include <stdio.h>

void Foo::DoSomething()
{
    FooImplementation * const self = (FooImplementation*) this;
    printf( "bar = %i", self->bar );
}
```

The main issues with this approach are that sizeof(Foo) doesn't give the correct value (hence the Create() function), and that it is a hack.  Personally i feel the productivity increase of reduced compile times makes this hack worth while.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so, I'm TOTALLY wrong. Riviera approached it with his comment.

My source was about 7:30 into -
http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-3-of-n/

However, going back over it, he was referring to "using" directives. I must have been braindead listening to it.

Interesting answers though, especially templatetypedef's. Thanks folks (and apologies for the trouble)